# Get filename of the chunk generated by NextJS withSass()

Tags: webpack, next.js

My `next.config.js` looks like this:

```
import path from 'path';
import glob from 'glob';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin from 'optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin';

import withSass from '@zeit/next-sass';

dotenv.config();

module.exports = withSass({
  distDir: '.build',
  webpack: (config, { dev, isServer }) => {
    if (isServer) {
      return config;
    }
    config.plugins.push(
      new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
        maxChunks: 1,
      }),
    );
    config.optimization.minimizer.push(
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({}),
    );
    return config;
  },
});
```

Here, I'm using the `withSass` module to concatenate all `.scss` files and merge them into a single payload that goes in the build directory with a hashed filename:

```
.build/static/css/styles.84a02761.chunk.css
```

Now, in my webpack config, is there any way to retrieve the filename generated by this module so I could use it to programmatically build my service worker for caching purposes? Ideally, I'd like to get the filename as it's generated and append it to something like a `.env` file for later use.